# WebBrowser Fires DocumentCompleted before ajax calls are completed

Tags: c#, .net

It seems that WebBrowser doesn't care if there are ajax calls in progress, it just fires DocumentCompleted when the main html and images are loaded...

So is it possible to know when the page including all ajax calls has been completed?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to implement async ajax calls.

[How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Or, on success, set flags that tell you when a call has returned.